# Multiplying integer with float gives bad result Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, multiplication, decimal-point

The problem is that when integer is multiplied with float, in cases like below mentioned, it returns value incremented by 1.

```
value = 9223372036854775807
factor = 1.0
offset = 0.0
y = round(value * factor + offset)

print long(y)

output => 9223372036854775808
```

While this is explained in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

I tried using

```
y = round(value * decimal.Decimal(factor) + decimal.Decimal(offset))
```

but without success.

Can someone please explain why is this happening and what's the solution with or without using decimal?

Thanks.

Comment: `value * decimal.Decimal(factor) + decimal.Decimal(offset)` works just fine. It's the Python 2.7 `round` call that's then converting that back to a `float`. (Python 3 would be fine here.) What effect did you want from the `round`? What type do you want the output `y` to have?

Comment: value, factor and offset are values parsed from other files, y value will therefore (without round), for example, be 8372697.567 or 7271661.123, what I need here is values with 0.5 or more rounded to upper value and less than 0.5 rounded to lower value. Just like round() works